# total column based on month in r

Tags: r

I am trying to summarize data based on month. For example, I have this data set:

```
x
        Date App Vol
1 2010-01-30   A 100
2 2010-01-28   B 140
3 2010-01-30   C 160
4 2010-02-28   A 110
5 2010-02-28   B 120
6 2010-02-28   C 300
```

I would like to be able to summary App data by each month. According to the data frame above, 
A should be 210, B = 260, C=460 etc.

I am using aggregate function ase below, but getting errors:

```
y<-aggregate(x$Vol, list(Month = format(as.POSIXct(x$Date), "%Y-%m")), sum)
```

any ideas?

Comment: that is typo on my end on the post, that is not the issue.

Comment: @Mike using ttmaccer's suggestion and your code it works for me.

Comment: @Tyler Rinker, I get this error: Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 3L, 6L, 36L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  sum not meaningful for factors

Comment: then `x$Vol` is a factor.  Use `str(x)` and see if Vol is a factor.  If it is use `x$Vol <- as.numeric(as.character(x$Vol))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with turning `Vol` into numeric (it got messed up somehow):

```
x$Vol <- as.numeric(as.character(x$Vol))
```

I can reproduce your eror by turning `Vol` into a factor as seen here:

```
x$Vol <- as.factor(x$Vol)
aggregate(x$Vol, list(x$App), sum)

#> aggregate(x$Vol, list(x$App), sum)
#Error in Summary.factor(1:2, na.rm = FALSE) : 
#  sum not meaningful for factors
```

Also you say:

```
I would like to be able to summary App data by each month. According to the 
data frame above, A should be 210, B = 260, C=460 etc.
```

If this is the case use:

```
x$Month <-  format(as.POSIXct(x$Date), "%Y-%m")
aggregate(x$Vol, list(x$Month, x$App), sum)
```

Otherwise use ttmacer's suggestion.

Comment: yes I had to convert my x$Vol to numeric. Great catch. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
x<-read.table(header=T,text="Date       App   Vol
    1 2010-01-30   A        100
    2 2010-01-28   B     140
    3 2010-01-30   C     160
    4 2010-02-28   A        110     
    5 2010-02-28   B         120      
    6 2010-02-28   C         300") 



y<-aggregate(x$Vol, list(Month = format(as.POSIXct(x$Date), "%Y-%m")), sum)
y<-aggregate(x$Vol, list(x$App), sum)
```

try using this data.

Comment: I keep getting this error: Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 3L, 6L, 36L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  sum not meaningful for factors